# ASP.net website - Session expire regardless of user activity

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have an ASP.net website with a login page. After login, users can read/search/fill-in data, export what they need and so on. The website is supported by a MSSQL and data are shown in Telerik radgrids. All of the above is working fine. It is not my code, someone did it for me.
The problem I am having is that regardless of users activities, they get logged out after 15 to 20 minutes.
The time out in the web.config file is set out at 60 minutes.

```
 <system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="60" />
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

I checked the content of the cookie and basically all it says is "expiration: at the end of the session".

This is driving me mad since few days now. Some help will be really appreciated.
What should I check/change to have a normal situation where users get logged out after 20 minutes idling and not while they are busy working?

Could this problem be related to the hosting server settings (1and1.com)?

Comment: Ensure no code is changing the Session timeout property.  IIS resets will clear the session, if it's hosted externally you probably won't have any control over an app pool recycle/iis reset etc.

Comment: I'd say it's more likely an issue with your authentication cookie rather than the session timeout.

Comment: @DarrenDavies, thanks for the suggestions. Is there a way to check if the pool is recycled?

Comment: @James, thanks. Can you suggest what to look for?

Comment: @FeliceM what does the configuration for your authentication cookie look like?

Comment: @FeliceM - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525613%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: @James, I do not see any in the web.config. Where should I look for?

Comment: @FeliceM see [authentication Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/532aee0e(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @FeliceM if you are using a custom login, you might need to change it from Windows to Forms. Then placing timeout="60" as well.

Comment: @DarrenDavies Thanks for the support. After big discussions with the provider and despite the fact that they did not admit problems on their side, without any change on my website code, the problem suddenly disappeared. So obviously the problem had something to do with their pool recycle/IIS as per your suggestion. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm having problems with sessions and 1&1 too. I'm using CakePHP and suddenly I could not store the session files in my own tmp directory. Now I have to use /tmp, and obviously I have no control over the timeout.